# rock, paper scissors tournament, win at least z times

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a rock, paper scissors (one wins, one loses) tournament with n players where everybody plays against eachother exactly once:

what's the maximum number, $z=z(n)$, of games that assure that at least one player has won z times?

The first thing i think is needed is to determine the number of matches, N, which is $N=\frac{(n-1)n}{2}$, now what i dont know is how  to calculate how many of those $N$ matches need to be played before someone has won at least $z$ times.

Answer (score 3):

Note that if $N \geq n(z-1)+1$, then by the Pigeonhole principle there must be some player who has won at least $z$ games. Thus setting $z = \lfloor (N-1)/n \rfloor + 1 = \lceil (n-1)/2 \rceil$ is always safe. To show that this is the best we can do, consider the following: all players sit in a circle. For the match between player $A$ and player $B$, let $A$ win if and only if $B$ is closer on $A$'s right side than on $A$'s left. For matches where $A$ and $B$ are directly across from one another, either $A$ or $B$ may win (this only happens when $n$ is even). If the results of the rock-paper-scissors matches follow this pattern, then the number of matches won by each player is easy to calculate: it is $(n-1)/2$ if $n$ is odd, and either $n/2$ or $n/2 - 1$ if $n$ is even. In either case, each player wins at most $z = \lceil (n-1)/2 \rceil$ games, so we could not have chosen $z$ to be any larger.